# Adding a PDF to a sqlalchemy database

Tags: python, pdf, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a simple `model` that I want to store the binary contents of a PDF file in a `data` attribute:

```
from app import db

    class Model(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        data = db.Column(db.PickleType, nullable=True)
```

I'm trying to add some arbitrary PDF file to the `data` attribute as follows:

```
@app.route('/')
def index() -> str:
    model = Model.query.get(1)
    model.data = open('./app/static/pdf/file.pdf', 'rb')
    db.session.commit()
    return ''
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object
[SQL: UPDATE model SET data=? WHERE model.id = ?]
[parameters: [{'data': <_io.BufferedReader name='./app/static/pdf/file.pdf'>, 'model_id': 1}]]
```

What is the correct way of doing this, please? How should I go about serializing a PDF file?

Thanks for any help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between

```
model.data = open('./app/static/pdf/file.pdf', 'rb')
```

and

```
model.data = open('./app/static/pdf/file.pdf', 'rb').read()
```

is the difference between to pickling a file handle (which has some unpickle-able parts) and pickling a byte array.

Comment: In your position, I'd consider whether PickleType is adding any value. A byte array stores just fine in a normal BLOB.

Comment: Awesome, so a `db.Column(db.LargeBinary, nullable=True)` instead?

Comment: Yup. You might need to set `length` depending on what Database you're using. There's a hint about MySQL in the docs.